# Eclipse relative indentation with classes inherited from the namespace

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, indentation

Hello, i am trying to make Eclipse-CDT (Indigo) to indent C++ class methods relativly to public/protected/private keywords; but expecting some troubles with classes which are inherited from some namespace; here is an illustration:

```cpp
// some namespaced class
namespace BarSpace {
    class Bar {

    };
}

// as it indented by eclipse:
class Foo1 : public BarSpace::Bar {
    public:
    void foo();
};
```

As you see - eclipse indenting foo() method wrong; not relativly to public: keywrod.
I've played a bit and found out that it is happens only when Foo* class inherited from namespaced class and so; such workaround may work:

```cpp
// workaround:
using namespace BarSpace;
class Foo2 : public Bar {
    public:
        void foo();
};
```

Only i don't want to pollute namespaces with my constructs. I want to have both relative indentation and namespaced inheritance at the same time; like follows:

```cpp
// as i want it to be indented:
class Foo3 : public BarSpace::Bar {
    public:
        void foo();
};
```

How can i configure Eclipse to work as i want?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an astyle plugin for eclipse. Install it and you can adjust many things.

astyleclipse.sourceforge.net/

Perhaps your problem can be solved this way too

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse -> Preferences -> C/C++ -> CodeStyle -> Formatter.

As of Eclipse Mars.